# Could not find or load main class NotifyAdministrator in java ant

Tags: java, ant

I write small snippet of code for learning "Execute java code" in ant

the program code

```
public class NotifyAdministrator {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String email = args[0];
    notifyAdministratorviaEmail(email);
    System.out.println("Administrator "+email+" has been notified");
}
public static void notifyAdministratorviaEmail(String email)
{
    System.out.println("Email Adress"+email+"See calendar");
}
```

}

the build.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="MyAnt_Test_1" basedir="." default="notify">
<target name="notify">
    <java fork="true" failonerror="yes" classname="NotifyAdministrator">
        <arg line="admin@test.com"/>
    </java>
</target>
</project>
```

I receive the error "Could not find or load main class NotifyAdministrator" as I Run build file in eclipse and command prompt.
Can you help me and answer Which part of program or build file have a problem? How I can fix it?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide classpath for your class in `java` ant task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

For instance:

```
<java fork="true" failonerror="yes" classpath="." classname="NotifyAdministrator">
    <arg line="admin@test.com"/>
</java>
```

assuming that NotifyAdministrator.class is in the same directory as build.xml and that you invoke ant in that directory.